# IOS app does not receive fire event from bluetooth device after connecting with it

Tags: ios, swift, bluetooth

I have a bluetooth device. When i fired device, IOS app receive fire event from it in `func centralManager(_ central: CBCentralManager, didDiscover peripheral: CBPeripheral, advertisementData: [String : Any], rssi RSSI: NSNumber)` method in `advertisementData["kCBAdvDataLocalName"]` But when i connect BLE bluetooth device with my app through **centralManager.connect(heartRatePeripheral)** method it did not receive fire event in any of the **CBPeripheralDelegate** methods. Please help me how to get event after connecting BLE device with IOS app. Below is my full code.

```
import UIKit
import CoreBluetooth

let heartRateServiceCBUUID = CBUUID(string: "FFC2")

class HRMViewController: UIViewController {

   @IBOutlet weak var heartRateLabel: UILabel!
   @IBOutlet weak var bodySensorLocationLabel: UILabel!

   var centralManager: CBCentralManager!
   var heartRatePeripheral: CBPeripheral!

   override func viewDidLoad() {
      super.viewDidLoad()

      centralManager = CBCentralManager(delegate: self, queue: nil)
      heartRateLabel.font = UIFont.monospacedDigitSystemFont(ofSize: 
      heartRateLabel.font!.pointSize, weight: .regular)
   }

   func onHeartRateReceived(_ heartRate: Int) {
       heartRateLabel.text = String(heartRate)
       print("BPM: \(heartRate)")
   }
}

extension HRMViewController: CBCentralManagerDelegate {
   func centralManagerDidUpdateState(_ central: CBCentralManager) {
   }

   func centralManager(_ central: CBCentralManager, didDiscover  
   peripheral: CBPeripheral, advertisementData: [String : Any], rssi 
   RSSI: NSNumber) {
       if advertisementData["kCBAdvDataLocalName"] as? String == 
           "SPS026A" {
           print(advertisementData["kCBAdvDataLocalName"])
           let data = 
            advertisementData[CBAdvertisementDataManufacturerDataKey]
            print("data ==\(data)")
            heartRatePeripheral = peripheral
            centralManager.connect(heartRatePeripheral)
        }
   }

   func centralManager(_ central: CBCentralManager, didConnect 
   peripheral: CBPeripheral) {
        print("Connected!")
        heartRatePeripheral.discoverServices([])
        heartRatePeripheral.delegate = self
    }
}

extension HRMViewController: CBPeripheralDelegate {
    func peripheral(_ peripheral: CBPeripheral, didDiscoverServices 
    error: Error?) {
         guard let services = peripheral.services else { return }
         for service in services {
             print(service)
             peripheral.discoverCharacteristics(nil, for: service)
         }
     }

     func peripheralDidUpdateName(_ peripheral: CBPeripheral) {

     }

     func peripheral(_ peripheral: CBPeripheral, 
     didDiscoverCharacteristicsFor service: CBService, error: Error?) 
     {
          guard let characteristics = service.characteristics else { 
          return }
          for characteristic in characteristics {
               if characteristic.properties.contains(.read) {
                    print("\(service): service : \ . 
                    (characteristic.uuid): properties contains .read")
                    peripheral.readValue(for: characteristic)
                }
               if characteristic.properties.contains(.notify) {
                     print("\(service): service : \ 
                     (characteristic.uuid): properties contains 
                     .notify")
                      peripheral.setNotifyValue(true, for: 
                      characteristic)
                }
            }
       }

       func peripheral(_ peripheral: CBPeripheral, didOpen channel: 
       CBL2CAPChannel?, error: Error?) {

       }

       func peripheralIsReady(toSendWriteWithoutResponse peripheral: 
       CBPeripheral) {

       }

       func peripheral(_ peripheral: CBPeripheral, 
       didUpdateNotificationStateFor characteristic: CBCharacteristic, 
       error: Error?) {
             print("Unhandled Characteristic UUID: \(characteristic)")
       }

       func peripheral(_ peripheral: CBPeripheral, didUpdateValueFor 
       characteristic: CBCharacteristic, error: Error?) {
             print("Unhandled Characteristic UUID: \(characteristic)")
       }
   }
```

Comment: Can u explain your problem?

Comment: I have one BEL device. when trigger it call and msg send to save mobile number to from application. Currently trigger event is got in didDiscover peripheral of centralManager without connect BEL device to core bluetooth. But when i connect BLE device with core bluetooth, app could not receive trigger event of BLE device. I want to get trigger event after connecting BLE device with core bluetooth, I dont want to get it in didDiscover peripheral method of CentralManager. I want to get it in Peripheral Delegate methods.

Comment: Can u tell me your BLE device name? Ex: HeartRateMonitor, RowerData.

Comment: Smart Safety Spray for women

Answer (score 1):

To discover all of the peripheral's services, you should pass `nil` to `discoverServices`, not an empty array.

```
heartRatePeripheral.discoverServices(nil)
```

By passing an empty array you are saying that you don't want to discover any services.

Comment: I have tried this. It list my services and their characteristics. After that I provide read and notify permission to my peripheral for characteristics and when i fire my device app does not receive fire event in didUpdateNotificationStateFor method .but if i do not connect device with app via centralmanager connect method, fire event received by app in didDiscover method in device mac address <d15eaef6 026a004d> where 00 changes to 01

Comment: You don’t actually have access to the MAC address, so I presume you mean the identifier. If you are discovering a peripheral with a different identifier then you either have multiple peripherals or you need to look at what your device is doing.

Comment: I have just one device. right now bluetooth scan method scan for peripheral after every 10 seconds. In didDiscover Peripheral method I get 'advertisementData["kCBAdvDataLocalName"]' = <d15eaef6 026a004d> every time. When i trigger device it change to 'advertisementData["kCBAdvDataLocalName"]' = <d15eaef6 026a014d> means 00 becomes 01

Comment: That doesn’t mean anything.  The peripheral’s `identifier` is what you want to track

Comment: `d15eaef6 026a004d` does not make sense at all for `kCBAdvDataLocalName`, and does not match your code, which explicitly looks for `SPS026A`. I believe you're looking at the wrong data. You're describing a lot of actions here that are not in your code above. You have a lot of loggings statements in your code; what gets printed out?